# ERC20Votes.sol clock() function returns Sepolia Ethereum block number on Sepolia Arbitrum Testnet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, governance

I have an ERC20Votes contracts on Sepolia Arbitrum testnet.

https://sepolia.arbiscan.io/address/0xc5A117C14F6117CB3870a628e02D2827B5E69471#readContract

**Why does the clock() function return the Sepolia Ethereum testnet block number, instead of the Sepolia Arbitrum testnet block number?** You can test it for yourself in the link above.

This is breaking the Openzeppelin governor contracts on Arbitrum, as the clock function is returning a block number in the past, making any new voting proposals end at a block number before the proposal start block.

Answer (score 0):

To get these Governance contracts to work for rollup blockchains (Arbitrum, Optimism etc) you have to override the clock in your ERC20Votes.sol to use time-based milestones instead of block-based milestones. More information here:

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/governance#token_2

Here is the code change to override the clock correctly:

```
    // Overrides IERC6372 functions to make the token & governor timestamp-based

    function clock() public view override returns (uint48) {
        return uint48(block.timestamp);
    }

    // solhint-disable-next-line func-name-mixedcase
    function CLOCK_MODE() public pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "mode=timestamp";
    }
```